# IDA - save work on kernel mode debugging

Tags: ida, dynamic-analysis, kernel-mode

I'm working with IDA pro on a kernel mode function (VMware + windbg) and I'm a annoying because I can't save the workstation state. IDA crash after 3 hours when I "quit and save memory status".
Is there a plugin or anything else that could make me able to save my work (variables rename, commentaries and  others) ?
Thanks for reading (and answers =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try debug IDA?  You may save your work via IDA [snapshot](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=415) feature.

Comment: I don't understand you (oh, my bad English). Did you try simple dump IDA db to IDC file?? (File->Produce file->"Dump data base to IDC file")

Comment: sorry wrong send, here is the full comment :
Hi, thanks for your answer ! I tried with the snapshot functionality but an initial database is requiered. 
In order : 
  - I start my virual machine
  - I attach IDA with winDBG to start kernel mode debbugging
  - I place comments and wanna save them for next session
My problem is that I only have a temporary database and I can't save it because it's only a live work session. 
Any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: (I'm probably hard to read, I'm french and my english is not awesome !) I never used IDC file, and I don't understand how it works for loading them. In my last message I mean that I try to save a live analysis state. So I probably need to save all the memory state of my current virtual machine if I wanna keep my comments and modifications. Is this message more clear ?

Comment: I'm never had some problem. I do understand you. Sorry but I'm thinking what I can't help you. Did you try read [this]?(http://www.hexblog.com/?p=92).  What version of IDA are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with IDC files and VM snapshot =)
I'm on IDA 6.4 and the snapshot function doesn't work in live debugging. 
My solution is to take a snapshot of my virtual machine (on VMware workstation) to have everytime the same kernel state. When I wanna reload my work, I begin to load the virtual machine snapshot then I attach IDA to my virtual machine with windbg and finally I can load my IDC file using the script file option.

Thank you very much for you answer, it really was helpful !